# Relating Gibbs free energy to spontanity

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

can we say that $$\Delta G =\Delta H-T\Delta S$$ is spontaneity criteria only if
$$\tag{$t,p =$ const}T_\text{system} = T_\text{surrounding}$$

Please see the image attached.
In Gibbs function what exactly is $t$?

[image]

Comment: If $T_{sys}\neq T_{surr}$, I don't think either $T$ would be constant, which is an assumption when stating spontaneous processes have $\Delta G < 0$

Comment: Even if the $T_{sys}$ changes, it's generally assumed that $T_{surr}$ doesnt change.  Other than that, I agree with you

Comment: In Gibbs the independent variables are P T and N. You have to integrate V S and Mu respectively. Ie SdT so u can still get Gibbs if you know S(entropy) as a function of T

Answer (score 0):

To generalize a little, if we assume $T$ is affected only by its surroundings then It is valid to require (by product rule and $q=mC_P\Delta T$) that $\Delta G < -\dfrac{Sq}{mC_P}$, where $q$ is the heat transferred in the time it takes for the system to convert from state A to state B, and $\Delta G$ is the "normal" definition:$\Delta H-T\Delta S$. It is then valid to say $\Delta G < 0$ *if* $T_{sys}=T_{surr}$ but **not** *only if*, as $S=0$ is also sufficient.